# How to show arabic text in android?

Tags: android, arabic

I want to show Arabic text from text file in android. in some phones and tablets it seems to be correct, but on some android devices it looks like the below text:

```
ا ل س ل ا م     ع ل ي ك م
```

Please help me how to show them correctly on every device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the problem here is that the text is not shown right-to-left. You should try using the [Bidi](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Bidi.html) class, or by specifying the following in your XML:

```
<EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"android:id="@+id/editText1" android:gravity="right">/EditText>
```

Comment: It's also possible that the device doesn't support Arabic characters shaping, even if it supports basic right-to-left display for Hebrew. It *may* work in a web browser, but supports varies wildly between different devices and OS versions.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the ttf file to the assets folder in your android project folder..Then set the typeface of the textview in the code.