# Spinner showing empty texts on scrolling and malfunctioning

Tags: android, spinner

So , what happens on scroll down suddenly i see empty texts.And then when i scroll up i see empty texts again.I got large data , like 114. and am recieving them correctly from server side. why is this happening? maybe cause they are arabic letters? Thank You very much for all the help.

```
>     ArrayList<Chapter> listChapter = response.body();
       String[] listValues = new String[listChapter.size()];
       for (int i1 = 0; i1 < listValues.length; i1++) {
                            listValues[i1] = listChapter.get(i1).getName();
                        }
       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                App.getCurrentContext(),
                                R.layout.spinner_item, listValues);adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
       spin1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066426/display-arabic-text-in-android-textview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923620/how-to-show-arabic-text-on-textview-on-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720347/how-to-show-arabic-text-in-android

Comment: try these and make sure your list is not empty

Comment: I had checkectextview, and i changed it to textview to solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display Arabic text in android textview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066426/display-arabic-text-in-android-textview)

Comment: not a duplicatee for anything, because my issue was solved by using textview instead of CheckedTextView